# Probability that a point escapes some region due to Gaussian noise

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose we have the following problem:

[image]

The dot is at $\mathbf{a}=(0,2)$ and the lines have directions $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$, both passing through the origin.

Suppose that now the dot suffers from additive white Gaussian noise, i.e.

$$\mathbf{a_w}=(0+W_1,2+W_2)$$

where both $W_i$ have zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$. They are independent.

I want to calculate the probability $p_e$ that $\mathbf{a_w}$ escapes the zone marked by the red lines. I've thought of doing the following:

$$p_e=\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{a_w}\mathrm{\ escapes\ in\ the\ horizontal\ axis})+\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{a_w}\mathrm{\ escapes\ in\ the\ vertical\ axis})-\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{a_w}\mathrm{\ escapes\ in\ both})$$

due to the probability of the union property. This would lead to:

$$\begin{align}
p_e&=\mathbb{P}(|W_1|>2)+\mathbb{P}(W_2<-2)-\mathbb{P}(|W_1|>2)\mathbb{P}(W_2<-2)\\
&=2Q\left(\frac{2}{\sigma}\right)+Q\left(\frac{2}{\sigma}\right)-2Q\left(\frac{2}{\sigma}\right)Q\left(\frac{2}{\sigma}\right)\\
&=3Q\left(\frac{2}{\sigma}\right)-2Q^2\left(\frac{2}{\sigma}\right)
\end{align}$$

Is this approach correct? Is there any other less "homemade" way to do this (i.e. more formal, in some sense)?

Comment: I don't understand why you think that this yields the probability of escaping across the red lines. Aren't you calculating the probability that the dot escapes the axis-parallel strip $[-2,2]\times[0,\infty]$?

Comment: @joriki You are totally right, I don't know why it seemed okay before. I'm pretty lost here. Could you help me figure out how this could be approached? Is there any simple way?

Comment: Out of curiosity (should probably start my own question), but given the structure of the noise and any space (2D to 4D), could one find the expected time to exit?

Comment: @TonyHellmuth Time? Where does time appear here?

Comment: @Tendero It doesn't! I'm just curious :) - I will post a question soon! :D

Comment: @TonyHellmuth Keep me posted, I wonder how that might be!

Comment: @Tendero So I have been pretty busy but I did manage to find [this](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~rsong/metep.pdf) paper on mean escape time for Levy processes. Very similar to what I am thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in luck, since the product of Gaussians in Cartesian coordinates with the same variance is rotationally invariant (since the exponent is a multiple of $r^2$, the squared distance from the origin). So you can rotate your coordinate system by $\frac\pi4$ to make the red lines axis-parallel and then do exactly the sort of inclusion–exclusion calculation that you tried in the unrotated system (except that now both factors in each product will be half-infinite).

Comment: Aha! That's very clever. So, now my dot would be located at $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$, and I could write $p_e$ as: $$p_e = Q\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sigma}\right)+Q\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sigma}\right)-Q\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sigma}\right)Q\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sigma}\right)$$ Is this correct?

Comment: @Tendero: Yes, that's correct!